# Callback methods 'title' and 'label' are getting called multiple times on single mouse over

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using a custom tooltip for chart.js (version 2).
The callback methods 'title' and 'label' are getting called multiple times on a single mouse over.

Is there any way to fix this?

Here is the code

```
options: {  
         tooltips: { 
             callbacks: { 
                title:function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    console.log("Hello");
                    Code to get tooltip data
                },
                label:function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    console.log("Hello")
                    Code to get tooltip data
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

"Hello" is getting displayed multiple times from 'title' and 'label' on a single mouse over.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code...

Comment: Can you provide the code you are referring to ?

Comment: Facing same issue in chartjs version 2.6.0